Issue with ld linker command on macOS
I am having a really bad time trying to sort out this problem with a NASM program that I'm currently writing.
Here is a snippet of what I am attempting to do:
$ nasm -fmacho64 main.asm && ld main.o && ./a.out
ld: Missing -platform_version option

